# Tee-like functionality in Windows, while being able to communicate with process via signals

Tags: python, windows, fortran, subprocess, signals

I am running a Fortran program for physical calculations in Windows 10, which is calling an external DLL for the main part of the computation. The subroutines from that print out their current status to the console, where the user is able to monitor it. When it gets stuck, you are able to abort it after the current iteration in a dignified way by setting a variable to a specific value. It then finishes properly, using all set output routines.

This I managed to do via the Fortran [SIGNAL](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIGNAL.html) functionality, catching SIGINT. It works perfectly fine when running the application in the Windows console.

However, it is quite useful to compare the output of different runs, or at least save them - a run can be several hours long and outputs so much that the console does not buffer it. I cannot just pipe the output to a file however, since this is extremely annoying to read / constantly update during runtime.

**What I would like to do:**

1. Show output in console
2. Write same output to file
3. Be able to communicate with program.

I tried this first in powershell with `.\application.exe | Tee-Object -Filepath output.txt`, which works but I cannot send the Ctrl+C signal anymore. Then I tried with Python scripts, even building a small GUI - the same, either I am not able to see the output or I cannot abort properly.

One such try, obviously with help from stackoverflow:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    try:
        with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end='') 
                f.write(line) 
                # print(line, end='', file=f, flush=True)
            p.wait
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        p.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
    exit(p.returncode)
```

In that case, if I set stdout=PIPE or stdout=f I can print it to the file, but after Ctrl+C I receive:

```
forrtl: The pipe is being closed.
forrtl: severe (38): error during write, unit -1, file CONOUT$
```

Without the stdout set, I can properly stop it, but not write the output to a file.

I don't care if this is done via batch, Python or something else, really. Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: there is [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) with tools converted from Unix/Linux to Windows - and there is `tee.exe`. Maybe it will work.

Comment: I kind of got it to work with that, although it is slow and hacky and you have to start it from a powershell:

`[console]::TreatControlCAsInput=$true`

`start powershell " Get-Content .\output.txt -wait"`
`.\bin\application.exe > output.txt`